# What features of Lisp are present in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lisp

I've read that Ruby has inherited many features from Lisp.

What features does Ruby have that likely have a Lisp heritage?

Comment: um, no, ruby has much fewer parens than lisp, and less than many other c like languages..

Comment: Expressions, (big)nums, symbols ... how fundamental do you want to get?  Just about every feature it has can be traced back to Lisp, directly or indirectly.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear; i guess i want to know less about the specific features (from what i hear alot of features of every modern language can be traced back to lisp) but more about a mind-set or spirit that ruby may or may not share with lisp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good read: http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2005/12/03/why-ruby-is-an-acceptable-lisp

See also, "how ruby borrowed a decades-old idea from LISP" http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/9/18/how-ruby-borrowed-a-decades-old-idea-from-lisp

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas, continuations and list comprehensions are probably the top three.

Comment: list comprehensions? how do i do those in ruby? ;)

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/89416 has a few ways. Not as pretty as Python's, but they're there.

Comment: Those aren't list comprehensions as the term is normally used. They're methods that operate on the list with a lambda. Which is still a lispy thing to do — they're just not list comprehensions.

Comment: There are no first class continuations in Lisp. They are in Scheme, which is a variant of Lisp.

Comment: There are no list comprehensions in Lisp, either, unless you count the LOOP macro of Common Lisp. (Or one of the innumerable comprehension macros that everybody writes themselves.) I think you mean "Higher order functions".